# Get data attribute from child

Tags: javascript, html

I have a dropdown option which has `data-value` assigned to them. At the moment, when a user selects an `li`, I'm trying to get the `data-value` assigned to the li they clicked on.

Have tried the following below:

```js
  var filters = {};
  $('.filters').on( 'change', function( event ) {
    var $select = $( event.target );
    var filterGroup = $select.attr('value-group');

    // filters[ filterGroup ] = event.target.value;
    // var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    var element = $(this).find('li');
    // var value = element.getAttribute('data-value');


    // $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });

    console.log("change " + element);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <div>
    <select value-group="location">
      <option data-value="*">LOCATIONS</option>
      <option data-value=".London">London</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I change to London, I'm expecting to see `change: .London` but I'm seeing `change [object Object]`

Comment: Nothing in your example `html` shows an `li` element. Why don't you set a `change` handler on the drop down and then grab the `data-value` of the dropdown's `option:selected`??? Or, just use the `value` property on the `option` elements, then just get the `value` of the drop down?

Comment: `element` is a jQuery object. It's outputted to the console as `[object Object]`, because you've concatted it to a string. If you want to get the data-attribute 'data-value' you should use jQuery's `.attr()` method like you did for 'value-group'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(this).find('option:selected')` to get selected option and using this get your custom attribute i.e : `attr('data-value')`.

**Demo Code** :

```js
//on change of select
$('select').on('change', function(event) {
//get slected option
  var $select = $(this).find('option:selected');
  //get custom attribute
  var filterGroup = $select.attr('data-value');
  console.log(filterGroup)
//duno why you need this 
  var element = $(this).find('li');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <div>
    <select value-group="location">
      <option data-value="*">LOCATIONS</option>
      <option data-value=".London">London</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the option's `value` instead

```js
  $('.filters').on( 'change', function( event ) {
    console.log("value " + $(event.target).children("option:selected").val());
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
  <div>
    <select value-group="location">
      <option value="*">LOCATIONS</option>
      <option value=".London">London</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```